# How to delete blob which has versioning enabled?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I have very strange behaviour with blob files on Azure storage.
Mind you I have soft delete enabled(7 days) and versioning enabled.
I am using a blobfuse connection to my machine.
When i try to delete a blob with no version, be it with rm -rf from VM or from portal. The blob is listed as deleted but not put in the 7 days deletion process. I have to manually go into versions and delete the version the blob somehow created when i deleted it and only then the blob goes into the deletion process and i get the Days until permanent deletion line.
Is there anyway i can delete(put into deletion process) a blob without having to manually remove all of it's version first?
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use lifecycle management to delete the versions after a certain amount of time. My understanding is that if you set it up this way the deleted blobs will become a previous version at first and then lifecycle management will then delete the version and it becomes soft deleted and retained for the amount of time you set for soft deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As from Microsoft Document blob will not go in 7 days of soft deletion until unless you will not specify the specific version of blob.** **If you are deleting the blob without mentioning the version it will be confusing part, which version you want delete and that version only go in soft deletion process

> If versioning and soft delete are both enabled for a storage account,
> then when you delete a blob, the current version of the blob becomes a
> previous version. No new version is created and no soft-deleted
> snapshots are created. The soft delete retention period is not in
> effect for the deleted blob.

You have to manually delete or select the version then only it will go in soft deletion process:

> Soft delete offers additional protection for deleting blob versions.
> When you delete a previous version of the blob, that version is
> soft-deleted. The soft-deleted version is preserved until the soft
> delete retention period elapses, at which point it is permanently
> deleted. To delete a previous version of a blob, call the Delete Blob
> operation and specify the version ID.

For more information do refer this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-overview#blob-versioning-and-soft-delete) on Soft Deletion.